# Single adverb for "Can't help but..."?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a more formal, more concise adverb with similar meaning to "can't help but"?

Comment: I think you probably mean 'verb'.

Comment: You can be *drawn* to something. Also, "I instinctively [verb]...."

Comment: No, I mean an adverb. "Instinctively" is close... "Naturally" is also good. Yet these all have connotations associated with psychology or biology. "Can't help but..." doesn't try to imply a cause; it're more casual; it has no association.

Answer (score 4):

I think the closest common word you may find is: "must."

*Example:*

- I can't help but ask where you got that sweater.
- I must ask where you got that sweater.

However, this isn't a universally great answer. For example:

- I can't help but wonder why the sky is blue
- I must wonder why the sky is blue.

Most examples for that type of sentence would involve the use of a time-based adverb indicating frequency:

- I continuously wonder why the sky is blue.
- I frequently wonder why the sky is blue.

The meaning of "can't help but" implies the speaker feels compelled, which makes the above examples less than perfect. Other ways of stating compulsion are unfortunately no more concise than the original phrase:

- I am compelled to wonder why the sky is blue.
- I am forced to wonder why the sky is blue.

Other options:

- I find myself wondering why the sky is blue.
- I surely wonder why the sky is blue.
- I indeed must wonder why the sky is blue. (Variation of the "must" form above, but with a different tone.)

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 particularly for making the point early in your answer that *can't help but* can't always be replaced by *must*. I still couldn't say exactly why *I must ask why the sky is blue* is an unlikely utterance. But I think it's a great example, because I'm sure most native speakers would agree it's not a very normal thing to say, even if they don't know why.

Comment: I would suggest 'have to' as an alternative.  "I have to ask where you got that sweater" and "I have to wonder why the sky is blue."

Comment: The _can help but_ construction is a negative polarity item, as can be seen by removing the negation from any of the sentences. This is not a trait of _must_, which is usable either plain or negated (though it only allows inside negation -- _must not `VP`_ means `Obliged Not to VP`; for `Not Obliged to VP` one hasta use _don't have to `VP`_). Also different.

Comment: I like what you say about compulsion. To turn it into an adverb, it would be "compulsively," right? But "compulsively" and "impulsively" are both rather strong compared to "can't help but..."

Comment: @Cameron I agree. For me, the difference is that "I can't help but" is something that we say figuratively. In fact, we can help it, but we use it as a figure of speech to imply a strong conviction. Using the adverb compulsively is literally equivalent, but it does not have the same connotation because it is not used as a figure of speech.